# Can you replace & with bitand in references?

Tags: c++, syntax, c++11

In C++, we can write `and` for `&&`, `or` for `||`, `bitand` for `&` and `bitor` for `|`.

Now I wonder whether `and` and `bitand` are only valid where those operators are meant, or also where references are defined (g++ 4.6.3 accepts `bitand` for references — rvalue references seem not to be supported in that version — but of course that might just be the compiler not catching the error).

In short: Is the following code valid C++?

```
int and x = 3;

int a;
int bitand y = a;
```

Of course I would never write such code (except maybe if participating in an obfuscated code contest), but is it actually valid?

Comment: You could compile it and find out, no?

Comment: `and`, `bitand`, etc. are just macros. You can use them wherever you like, so yes, you can do that.

Comment: (p.s. "except maybe if participating in an obfuscated code contest": it's already been done :P)

Comment: @STLDeveloper: No. As I wrote, I *did* compile it, and g++ accepted it. And as I explicitly wrote, that doesn't tell me anything about if it *should* accept it.

Comment: +1 for bringing this up.

Comment: @Dave: They are *not* macros (neither in g++ as a simple `#ifdef` test reveals, nor in the standard as the citation in the — now deleted — answer by Andy Prowl showed).

Comment: Better yet: `virtual compl T() {}`. "Did you forget to make the compl operator virtual?"

Comment: @celtschk ah ok, I'm wrongly transferring C knowledge (which has the iso646 header where they *are* macros)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to C++11, 2.6/4:

> **In all respects of the language**, each alternative token behaves the same, respectively, as its primary token

So `int and a = 5;` is perfectly valid, though also perfectly insane.

---

More examples:

```
struct ete
{
    compl ete();
    int egr()and;
};
```